# break and label, "The label MyLabel is missing"

Tags: java, break, labeled-statements

I have a code like this:

```
if(condition1)
{
    break MyLabel;
}
while(true)
{
    //some code here
    MyLabel: if(condition2) break;
    //more code here
}
```

and I get this error:

> The label MyLabel is missing.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can only break to a label that is on a *textually enclosing* statement.  In your example, the label is NOT on a statement that encloses the `break` statement.

(For what it is worth, even higher-level languages that support `goto` don't allow you to jump into the middle of a loop from the outside.  I'm thinking of C ... and older languages like FORTRAN.)

Java allows you to break out, but breaking in is illegal ... and will get you arrested :-)

<sub>(Sorry, I couldn't resist it.  For those who don't get the joke, a "break in" is when someone enters your house to steal stuff - see ["break and enter"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_and_enter) ... )</sub>

Comment: I like to see the word _arrested_ in a topic about labels. IMHO good use cases for labels are VERY rare.

Comment: Java explicitly disallows goto by reserving the word but not using it. Perhaps Ali is looking for Intercal's [COME FROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMEFROM) statement?

Answer (score 8):

You **can't** use labels as goto in that **general** way.
Use labels if you want to goto a higher level of **nested** code.

for example

```
l1: while
 l2: while
  l3: while
   break l1
   l4: while
```

Comment: Note however that the label is an identifier in Java, not a number.

Comment: He can use labels as goto but he MUST NOT ;)