# What does break statement do in java?

Tags: java, break

Does anyone knows  what the `group_skip` do?

Maybe it is a basic programming, but I've been programming using Java for some years and just found it today.

```
group_skip: do {
    event = stepToNextEvent(FormController.STEP_OVER_GROUP);
    switch (event) {
        case FormEntryController.EVENT_QUESTION:
        case FormEntryController.EVENT_END_OF_FORM:
            break group_skip;
    }
} while (event != FormEntryController.EVENT_END_OF_FORM);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do not post images of text, instead copy-and-paste the actual text directly into your post. Images of text are not easily parsable, searchable, or accessible.

Comment: Edited it! Sorry for that :D

Comment: It is a label, which can be used to break out of a statement

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a [labelled loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html), when `break group_skip;` statement is executed, it will jump out of the do while loop which is labelled as `group_skip`

```
boolean isTrue = true;
    outer: for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        while (isTrue) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            break outer;
        } // end of inner while
        System.out.println("Outer loop"); // does not print
    } // end of outer loop
   System.out.println("Good Bye");
```

This outputs

```
Hello
Good Bye
```

You can get the concept clear here.

- There is a labelled `for` loop called `outer` and there is inner `while` loop
- When inner for loop is being executed, it encounters `break outer;` statement
- The `outer for loop` has a `System.out.println"Outer loop"`  statement but that does not get printed.
- This is because `break outer` causes the control to jump out of labelled `for` loop directly

Now this example for `continue` statement

```
outer: for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            continue outer;
        } // end of inner loop
        System.out.println("outer"); // this won't print
    } // end of outer loop
    System.out.println("Good bye");
```

This prints

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Good bye
```

- There is a labelled `for` loop here and an inner `for` loop
- Inner `for` loop prints `Hello` and continues to the `outer` loop.
- Because of this, the statements below inner `for` loop are skipped and `outer` loop continues to execute.
- At the end of `outer` for loop, `Good Bye` is printed

Hope this makes everything clear.

Comment: Thanks Prasad for the very clear example! Btw, you don't have the `System.out.println("Good Bye");`;D

Comment: Made mistake whily copy pasting it :) .. thanks for pointing it out Rendy

Answer (score 8):

`group_skip` is a label. Labels allow you to break or continue specific loops when you've got them nested.

[Here's what Oracle has to say on the subject.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score 4):

when ever we use simple break statement then we can only transfer control from inner most loop to the outer most (if we have nesting of loops). for exampel

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
    if(i==5){
      break;
    }
}
statement x;
```

will simply transfer the control to **statement x**. But if you use it inside nested loops then it will work differently.

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
 for(int j=0; j < 10; j++)
    if(i==5){
      break;
    }
 }
statement y;
}
statement x;
```

in this case it will send the control to **statement y**. If you want to send the control from innermost loop to either outermost loop or outside the loop then you need such a break statements with labels. Just do it from your self and you will see interesting output.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`group_skip` is a label used for things like break. (Also goto and jump in other languages)

In java specifically it would be used to break from a code block identified by the label, behaving just like a `break` statement in a while loop, except breaking from a labeled code block.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802287/break-and-label-in-java) is some more discussion on the topic