# Restart loop with next value

Tags: java, loops

How is it possible to start over the current loop with the next value.
By this, I mean that if my function is

```
for(int i=0; i<=2; i++)
{
   if(i==1) FUNCTION;
   print(i);
}
```

then output should be "02".

Comment: You can maintain a `begin` variable : `for(int i=begin; i<=2; i++){...}`

Comment: What do you mean start over? Starting from a mid-value ?

Comment: Why not reconsider using a different increment-rule?

Comment: I will use it for far more complicated loops, where I need it to do exactly what I wrote. The example is only there to sharpen my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<=2; i++)
{
   if(i==1){
     continue;
   } 
   print(i);
}
```

The **[continue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)** statement helps you with this. If a condition is met, skip the loop body and then **continue** the loop body for the next iteration.

You can find more information about `break` and `continue` statements in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334917/what-does-break-group-skip-do/17334944#17334944) example.

Comment: @rags Thanks for the edit. Its now more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if(i==1) {
           i=0;
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
```