# What is this error mean label z is missing in break statement?

Tags: java

Hi in the below code i am trying to come out of for loop using break and label but i am getting the following error. `Label Z is missing.` Please help me the code is given below. And please mention why this error occurs.

```
public class Breaker {
    static String o = "";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        z:
        o = o + 2;
        for(int x = 3; x < 8; x++) {
            if(x==4) break;
            if(x==6) break z;
            o = o + x;
        }
        System.out.println(o);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802287/break-and-label-the-label-mylable-is-missing) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because in your code label z: is not enclosing any loop:

Try the below code: I have just added a pair of braces after label z: you will not get any compilation error and your code will run.

```
public class Breaker {
    static String o = "";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        z:
        {
        o = o + 2;
        for(int x = 3; x < 8; x++) {
            if(x==4) break;
            if(x==6) break z;
            o = o + x;
        }
        System.out.println(o);
     }
    }
 }
```

Comment: well that was a great unique idea. where can i find official oracle definition for using break statment in detail(or any other trusted source).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 1):

In order to break out of a loop, you have to label the loop statement, not some other statement. `break someLabel` only makes sense together with nested loops though. Otherwise you can just use a plain `break`.

Comment: how do i label the loop statement.

Comment: You put `z:` immediately before the `for`. Looking at your code again, you may be trying to do something that's not allowed in Java (jump to some other statement from inside a loop).

Comment: Thanks peter. But i was still wondering why java does not allow this, as i am not jumping to any other statement i am just coming out of for loop.

Comment: You can think of it this way: `break someLabel` jumps out of the loop to the position *after* the labeled statement. However, in your case (since you've labeled `o = o + 2;`) this would mean to jump right *before* the loop (and enter it again), which isn't allowed. You should only ever label loop statements, in which case you'll be fine. Also make sure you understand the difference between `break` and `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void twoNum( int num, int val )
{
OUTER_LOOP: // OUTER_LOOP is a label
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ )
  {
      for ( int j = 0 ; j < num ; j++ )
      {
         if ( i + j >= 2 * val )
            break OUTER_LOOP ;
         val = val / 2 ;
      }
  }
  // break comes here if it runs
}
```

When you write:

```
  break OUTER_LOOP ;
```

the label, `OUTER_LOOP`, must be a label for an enclosing loop. Usually, this is not the innermost enclosing loop since we can just use a plain `break` statement, instead of a "break with a label".
The `label` must be before a enclosing `loop` of the `break` statement.

[Incremental Java](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/ControlFlow/break.html)

Other than that sysntax error(Place of the `lable`),If you understand from the above summary,In your case you just `break`