# Return and break statement error

Tags: java, android, return, break

I am having trouble in one of my programming statements in android, it keeps giving me the error that label 230 is missing but I don't know what am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

This is the program below ;

```
public static void calculateGPA()
  {
    totalHours = 0.0D;
    totalValue = 0.0D;
    int i = 0;
    if (i >= 8)
    {
      Object[] arrayOfObject = new Object[1];
      arrayOfObject[0] = Double.valueOf(totalValue / totalHours);
      GPA = String.format("%.2f", arrayOfObject);
      if (!GPA.equals("NaN"))
        break label230;
      GPA = "0.00";
    }
    while (true)
    {
      return;
      int j = collegeGradeSpinner[i].getSelectedItemPosition();
      int k = collegeHourSpinner[i].getSelectedItemPosition();
      if ((j != 0) && (k != 0))
        switch (j)
        {
        default:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        }
      while (true)
      {
        i++;
        break;
        totalValue += k * 4;
        totalHours += k;
        continue;
        totalValue += k * 3;
        totalHours += k;
        continue;
        totalValue += k * 2;
        totalHours += k;
        continue;
        totalValue += k * 1;
        totalHours += k;
        continue;
        totalHours += k;
      }
      label230: gpaTextView.setText(GPA);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your label exists inside enclosed block. You cannot "break in" this block: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802287/break-and-label-the-label-mylable-is-missing

Comment: Is this code has been generated through a tool because there are lot of areas that can be improved in your code. e.g. claculation of GPA can be done simpley as follows GPA = String.toString(Math.round(totalValue/totalHours, 2)); based on your requrment this can be done even more simpler way

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have a direct goto due to its language structure. If anything, direct gotos become unreadable and unmaintaneable very easily.

You can put a label as `labelname:for(...` with a for or while loop, and use `break labelname` or `continue labelname` to exit or start the next iteration of the loop, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`break` can only exit a loop that you're currently in. It cannot be used to go from point A to any arbitrary point B.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can't use `break` as a `goto` and just jump anywhere, especially not into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not a good practise you can achieve your requriement using java blocks as follows

```
label230: {
   if(i >= 8) {
     .....
     if(!GPA.equls("NaN") {
       break label230;/* Once you break here, it will take you out of the block*/
     }
     ....
     while(true) {
      ....
     }
   }
}// label230 block ends.
gpaTextView.setText(GPA);
```