# Is label in java make spaghetti code?

Tags: java, label, goto

I've just read about spaghetti code ( wiki [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)) that "goto" statement creates, I wonder if label in java makes spaghetti code?

I just interested in this because one of my old question about break and label in java that I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802287/break-and-label-the-label-mylabel-is-missing)

Comment: why do you need a label in your code?

Comment: Show us an example with labels and someone might tell you what is wrong with your code.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I dont need label in my code, actually right now I'm not even code in java(I'm coding in groovy) but after reading that article I was thinking about this.

Comment: @SteveTaylor as I said to Rafael I was just thinking about this, it's not a real problem that I have

Comment: @AliAmiri even it is technically possible to use labels, I do not see a real reason when I will need them. I write on java for 15 years, and I did not need to use labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with labels is that they are rarely used which means they are surprising and possibly confusing for a reader. e.g

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
System.out.println("Hello SO");
```

At first glance, that doesn't even look like valid Java code, but it is.

Because labels tend to be used only when the are really needed, and sometime not used when they should have been used IMHO, they don't lead to spaghetti code in Java in reality.

Answer (score 3):

Labels are so rarely needed/used that no, not really. Also you can't jump to a label, you need to break to it, so you can't get the similar kind of confusion as with filling the code with `goto whereever` statements.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, this "can't jump to a label" was a good point.